# How to extract compileSdkVersion from build.gradle to be used in .travis.yml?

Tags: android, build.gradle, travis-ci

I would like to automatically extract the values of `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` from *app/build.gradle*:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
```

The extracted values should replace the hardcoded values in `.travis.yml`:

```
env:
  global:
    - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=24
    - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.3
```

I would like to avoid defining the values twice since it one has to remember to update both everytime the values change.

## Intermediate state: compileSdkVersion

The following line works on the shell to extract `24` from *app/build.gradle*:

```
$ grep -H compileSdkVersion app/build.gradle | grep -o "[0-9]\+
```

Running the same  on Travis CI like this:

```
env:
  global:
    - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=(`grep -H compileSdkVersion app/build.gradle | grep -o "[0-9]\+"`)
    - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=27.0.3
```

causes the following error:

> $ export ANDROID_API_LEVEL=(`grep -H compileSdkVersion app/build.gradle | grep -o "[0-9]\+"`
>   /home/travis/.travis/job_stages: eval: line 57: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'

## Intermediate state: buildToolsVersion

Extracting the `buildToolsVersion` still does not work perfectly.

```
$ grep -H buildToolsVersion app/build.gradle | grep -o '[\.0-9]\+'
```

> .
>   27.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `grep` commands extract the `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` within the *Travis CI* environment:

```
env:
  global:
    - ANDROID_API_LEVEL=`grep -H compileSdkVersion app/build.gradle | grep -Po "\d+"`
    - ANDROID_BUILD_TOOLS_VERSION=`grep -H buildToolsVersion app/build.gradle | grep -Po "\d+.\d+.\d+"`
```